# Estimating camera's offset to its true position

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I have the following problem:

I get a 360 RGB image in a room.

- I've the 3D model of this room, hence, I can generate a 3D nominal mask of the room (1-wall, 2-ceiling, 3-floor, 4-door, etc..) in a specific location (x0,y0,z0,roll0,pitch0,yaw0)
- I can also generate the depth map of this location.

My model has to predict whether the generated mask+depth match with the RGB frame, and **if not** what are the *dx, dy, d_yaw* of the offset.

I've implemented pix2pix discriminator that receives a concatenated tensor of the [RGB, one-hot mask, depth] and yields the (dx, dy, d_yaw).
obviously, if there is a perfect match, dx=dy=dyaw=0.

Unfortunately my model isn't converging. I've tried everything, and it's a reasonable "request" from this model, since a human can roughly guess this offset if he looks on the images.

what would you suggest?